# CSS trouble with responsive background image of a div

Tags: html, css, image, background, responsive

I am trying to make a background image of a div cover the screen on both desktop and mobile devices. It is working perfectly on desktop, but no matter what I try, the image appears zoomed in on mobile.

This is the page: https://www.smithbars.com/tappd/

This is the CSS for < div class="section1" >

```
/*desktop*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
.section1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(TAPPD1_.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: #000;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
}

/*mobile*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.section1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(TAPPD1_.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
}
}
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: maybe on mobile, much more like a portrait layout kind, you could set another version of your background-image or set it to  background-size:auto 100%  ?? You have to deal with the ratio of your image and the *landscape* vue of your layout . it can also mean empty sides or top/bottom areas unless stretching it doesn't matter

Comment: I can't reproduce this: "the image is zoomed in to just a small corner in the top left of the entire image on mobile". It might help to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to use `background-size: cover` which maintains the aspect ratio of the image.

`cover` tells the browser to make sure the image always covers the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges.

Change:

```
background-size: cover;
```

to:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

The image loses its aspect ratio but you get your wish.

Comment: I do want it to maintain the aspect ratio, but with either of the above, the image is zoomed in to just a small corner in the top left of the entire image on mobile. Cover is working fine on desktop, I just don't know why it is zooming in on mobile.